# Creating a custom Sitecore NuGet package containing Unicorn files

Tags: helix, nuget

**Background**

We have a `Sitecore 9.1.1` project following `Helix` principles and wish to create `Nuget packages` from some of the custom layer projects (e.g. Customer.Foundation.Dictionary, Customer.Foundation.Assets, Customer.Feature.Article, etc).

The idea is that these `NuGet packages` can be used on new projects, such that we can re-use logic across projects.
We also utilize Unicorn for serialization in our project.

I found a lot of information about creating `NuGet packages` and some documentation on how to create Sitecore `NuGet packages` if I was using TDS, however, I have not found anything describing my use-case.

**My suggested approach**

The way I imagine it could work would be something along these lines:

```
1) NuGet package following convention-based structure (https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/create-packages/creating-a-package)

2) Content folder contains the serialized items

3) Content/App_Config/.....Serialization.Config contains stand-alone Unicorn configuration (this configuration needs to work as-is and not rely on existing config). Serialization folder points to the same folder as the script in step 4) copies to

4) Tools folder could contain PowerShell script that copies Serialization items to a location that follows Helix principles (i.e. [Layer]/Feature/Serialization
```

Is there anyone who tried to build `NuGet packages` of custom Sitecore components (with Unicorn), who can point me in a direction? Any advice regarding how to structure the NuGet package is much appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would organise the package something like this

```
- /
  - bin/
    - Customer.Foundation.Dictionary.dll
    - ... etc
  - App_Config/
    - Include/
      - Feature/
        - Customer/
          - Customer.Foundation.Dictionary.Serialisation.config
  - App_Data/
    - Unicorn/
      - Feature/
          - Customer.Foundation.Dictionary/
            - ... your yaml files here
```

The config would specify a `targetDataStore` relative to webroot; e.g. `~/App_Data/Unicorn/$(configurationName)`.

Comment: Thanks for your feedback - just what I was looking for. I am using Sitecore PaaS (Azure WebApps) and for deployment we use Azure DevOps. Azure DevOps has an option to leave the App_Data folder alone during deployment, hence I'd rather add my unicorn files to another folder (e.g. 'Data') which does not reside under App_Data. That way, if I delete any template, I can be sure, that the deployed files are always reflecting the actual state, but I guess that is personal preference

Comment: I actually do the same on a project I'm on. Everything gets deployed to my Azure app somewhere else, then I `robocopy /mir` it into App_Data as a post deployment step. But there are many ways to set this up, this is just one example.

Comment: I was hoping to get your thoughts on that aswell - thanks again!